# Live Cordova Android App suddenly fails at startup since recent Android or Security Update (March 2016)

Tags: android, jquery, angularjs, cordova

Has anyone experienced their Cordova app freezing up or having Non responsive UI (buttons not working)?

How do I debug this kind of situation (see below)?

**I am using:**  Cordova 6.1.1 and Android 5.1.1 .. The code has AngularJS and jquery in it.

**More Info:**
 My Cordova app (linked below) on Google Play has been freezing up and having non responsive buttons (they press but dont fire) on a lot of Android devices, it all started a few weeks ago. Many people can not get past the first screen they encounter after the splash screen hides. I believe it's because of a recent Security Update on Android that caused this, because the app has not been updated in a long while and I have been getting lots of feedback that it just stopped working on various newer Android devices.

It has mostly affected Samsungs and the devices of Android 5.0.1 and later. Even earlier versions of the app freezes up on these devices (these earlier versions used Cordova 5.0).

The app runs fine on iOS and on various Android devices, like my Nexus 5 and my Galaxy S3. Unfortunately I dont have a device that is affected.

**Debugging/Troubleshooting:**

In Genymotion, it runs fine, except on Android 6.0 emulators, in which it runs for 3 seconds then goes black. So I cant use Gap Debug to see what's going on. System Logs for the emulator are hard to read through and I havent caught any useful info in them.

Also, I have tried a Hello World project with the same Plugins and Config file, and the Hello example app runs fine in the Android 6 emulator. So I know it's not those that are making my app crash.

I am going to have to break down and get an affected device (like Galaxy S6 or S7) because I am about to run out of options.

[Will update and add to this thread when I have more info to deliver]

**GooglePlay App Link for BREAK TIME:**

**https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vergeretail.connect.breaktime&hl=en**

...

~Jeff

Comment: I've had similar experiences over the years with my app breaking on a particular device (like a Galaxy S5 or whatever) and my approach has been to buy one on Craigslist, eBay, etc. and then run on the actual device with GapDebug. You can always resell it after you figure out the weirdness. Gotta say, Galaxies in particular have been a pain in the arse for me, but so many people have them I can't just ignore it when things go south.

Comment: Good suggestion, will be doing just that. I was just talking to someone about it being a good idea to have the latest Galaxy on hand if you are working with Cordova and Android. 
  Still hoping someone else was affected by ab recent security update on Android, they might have some insight with their Cordova fix/work around.

Comment: Experiencing same issue and can’t figure out what’s causing it. The same application runs on iOS and its perfotmance is excellent. The app on Android freezes / crashes roughly after 10 clicks or so.